# lint warning: parseInt missing radix parameter

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have the following code that gives the warning described in the title:

```
          year: parseInt(dateParts[0]),
               ......................^
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 113, accepted):

See [the manual for `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt); it takes 2 arguments. The second one tells it which number base you want to use. This is almost always going to be `10` (decimal).

```
parseInt(dateParts[0],10)
```

If you don't specify it, then it will be inferred from the data.

> If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
> (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
>
> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10
> (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.
> ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers
> support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using
> parseInt.
>
> If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
> (decimal).

Some years after I wrote the above, things have changed. Now:

> The ECMAScript 5 specification of the function parseInt no longer allows implementations to treat Strings beginning with a 0 character as octal values. Many implementations have adopted this behavior as of 2021.

… but you still should use a radix, at least for browser side code, because not all implementations have caught up.